# change default gallery image size on impresspages

Tags: json, themes, size, impresspages

i try to change the default gallery size over the theme.json , but the result always same (square size picture like 200 x 200 px)

```
"imageGallery": { /* For responsiveness and optimization it should the size as it would appear on the widest block */
            "width": 295,
            "height": 164
        }

"gallery": { /* For responsiveness and optimization it should the size as it would appear on the widest block */
                "width": 200,
                "height": 164
            }
```

i using the new version of ip 4.4.0 , i dont have this pb in old version.

So how i can change the default gallery image size ? and which variable true "imageGallery" or "gallery" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration is based on widget's name. v4.x has only "gallery" widget. "imageGallery" is a leftover from earlier versions.

This configuration defines the size of an image that should be cropped. Despite that, some themes doesn't care of a real image size. They force image to form a particular number of columns. This makes sure that images take the full width (from left to right).

If you want to change this behavior, you need to override theme styles or the skin of this widget.

Another point, when change this configuration you must reinstall the theme for changes to take action. To do that, you need to install a different theme and install back the current one.